# AllJoyn: Reconnect to a device after session has been lost

Tags: java, session, alljoyn

What is the best way in AllJoyn to reconnect to a known device after the session has been lost (e.g. due to connectivitiy issues)?

I have already registered a `SessionListener` and get notified with a `sessionLost` event. Now I want to find the device again automatically as soon as the reason for the lost session is resolved (e.g. connectionvity re-established).

I thought I would just call `busAttachment.whoImplements()` periodically to get notified with an `Announced` message once the device is reachable again. I could detect by the about data if it is my previously known device or not. However, I don't receive any announced message.

What is the correct/best way to reconnect to a device?
I am using the java library in case this is relevant.